# Build failed with exception

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

My build fail when i run the `./gradlew wrapper` and i receive this message:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'RxRedux'.

  > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
  >   Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1.
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.pom
  >        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.jar
  >    Required by:
  >        project :
  >   Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1.
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.pom
  >        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.jar
  >    Required by:
  >        project : > io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:4.2.0
  >        project : > io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:4.2.0 > io.realm:realm-transformer:4.2.0
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your project-level `build.gradle` file is requesting that `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1` be added to the classpath, but it does not have `google()` in the list of repositories.

You want that `buildscript` closure to look like:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}
```

(notice the `google()` line)